# Combine two PHP lines of a command

Tags: php

I have these two lines of command:

```
$x = explode('/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
echo ($x[0]);
```

How can I combine them into one line? I tried this, but I got an error:

```
echo ( explode('/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])[0] );
```

Comment: What's the point of doing that? BTW, what you want works fine on PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, unless you've got [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Answer (score 3):

Up from PHP version 5.4, you can use this:

```
$x = explode('/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])[0];
```

In lower versions, you can't. In most cases, it makes your code less readable anyway.

See [PHP 5.4 new features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.ph) `function array-dereferencing`

Comment: Side info: it's called `function array dereferencing` (http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Answer (score 2):

You could force it like this:

```
echo current(explode('/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]));
```

But it flies in the face of strict standards, and I don't see a *good* reason for ever wanting to cram it onto a single line.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(array('0'=>explode('/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])));
```

Output:

**Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => img [2] => index.php ) )**